# How to update a summary data.frame field with a value from a different data.frame in R?

Tags: r

I'm creating a summary data.frame with counts, N and a percentage.
The summary data.frame has names -> category, n, count and percentage.
The counts data.frame has names -> category, count.
category is character. Often the rows in the counts data frame will be less than the rows in the summay.

The way I'd do this in MSSQL is

```
update summary
set summary.count = counts.count
from summary
inner join counts
on summary.category = counts.category
```

How could this be done in R?

Supporting code.

```
summary <- data.frame(category=c("apples","oranges","pears"),N=10,count=0,percentage=0)
> summary
  category  N count percentage
1   apples 10     0          0
2  oranges 10     0          0
3    pears 10     0          0
> counts <- data.frame( category=c("apples","pears"), count = c(5,5) )
> counts
  category count
1   apples     5
2    pears     5

# desired outcome after processing
> summary
  category  N count percentage
1   apples 10     5          0.5
2  oranges 10     0          0
3    pears 10     5          0.5
```

Comment: Try `inner_join` from the package `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks ... I discovered the merge command by searching for R data.frame union.

Comment: Yeah, that works too. I just am so used to `dplyr`. :)

Comment: Downvoters ... please comment if you think it's a not valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the merge command after searching for R data.frame union.

```
> summary <- data.frame(category=c("apples","oranges","pears"),N=10)
> summary
  category  N
1   apples 10
2  oranges 10
3    pears 10
> counts <- data.frame( category=c("apples","pears"), count = c(5,5) )
> counts
  category count
1   apples     5
2    pears     5
> merged <- merge( summary, counts, by="category", all.x = TRUE)
> merged
  category  N count
1   apples 10     5
2  oranges 10    NA
3    pears 10     5
> merged[is.na(merged)] <- 0
> merged
  category  N count
1   apples 10     5
2  oranges 10     0
3    pears 10     5
> merged["percentage"] = merged$count / merged$N
> merged
  category  N count percentage
1   apples 10     5        0.5
2  oranges 10     0        0.0
3    pears 10     5        0.5
```

To see an overview on how merge maps to SQL joins see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)